# File Reading into 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

in class definition

```
 public String[,] Sodoku_Gri = new String [9, 9];

    public void populate_grid_by_file()
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("data.txt");

        // read a line of text
        String store_data_from_file =  tr.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < Sodoku_Gri.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Sodoku_Gri.GetLength(1); j++)
            {

                Sodoku_Gri[i, j] = __________??
            }
        }
        tr.Close();
    }
```

inside the data.txt there is written "1--2--3--3-4-4-5---7-3-4---7--5--3-6--7---4--3-2--4-5-------3--2-6--7---4---4--3-"
i have to read it from the file and place them in 2d array in c#! it was easy in c++. Am a beginner! In c++ we should indexing in strings too to access every char in a string! i can i write this data in my 2d array? so that 81 spaces in the Sodoku_Grid[9,9] are filled with data from file!

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing 2d array in c# through for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769448/printing-2d-array-in-c-sharp-through-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to move your `tr.ReadLine()` into your innermost loop.
2. You can access individual characters in a string with an indexer:

   `Sodoku_Gri[i,j] = store_data_from_file[j]`

So it's pretty easy in C# as well.

Comment: it says cannot convert implicitly type char to string! though both sodoku_gri and store_data_from_file type is String!

Comment: Well, that's a data structure issue, right? do you want a 9x9 grid of single character strings? You could use the char's ToString() method to make that happen. Or would it be easier to have an array of 9 strings, each 9 characters in length?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your Sodoku_Gri is a bidimensional char array declared in this way

```
char[,] Sodoku_Gri = new char[9,9];
```

and the line contains the position of known numbers of a Sudoku game then
the index to correct char should be calculated in this way

```
Sodoku_Gri[i, j] = store_data_from_file[i*9+j];
```

(by the way, that line result in an invalid sudoku schema)

**EDIT:** Seeing your comment below then, if Sodoku_Gri is declared as

```
string[,] Sodoku_Gri = new string[9,9];
```

then you need to add a string conversion to the indexed char

```
Sodoku_Gri[i, j] = store_data_from_file[i*9+j].ToString();
```

Comment: but store_data_from_file is just a string how can u play with it like [i*9+j]

Comment: You can read a char from an input string like you do in C++ simply indexing its position inside the string. Supposing i=1 and j=1 then the char at 10 position is retrieved and assigned to Sodoku_Gri.