# printing 2d array in c# through for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

This is my filing function that takes data from the file and places it in the array:

```
public void populate_grid_by_file()
    {
        String store_data_from_file = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
            {
                store_data_from_file = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        string[] line = store_data_from_file.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] alphabet = store_data_from_file.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.Length; j++)
            {
                Sodoku_Gri[i, j] = alphabet[j];
            }
        }            
    }
```

Here is whats written in the file:

```
1--2--3--

3-4-4-5--

-7-3-4---

7--5--3-6

--7---4--

3-2--4-5-

------3--

2-6--7---

4---4--3-
```

This is what I want it to print:

```
1 - - 2 - - 3 - -
3 - 4 - 4 - 5 - -
- 7 - 3 - 4 - - -
7 - - 5 - - 3 - 6
- - 7 - - - 4 - - 
3 - 2 - - 4 - 5 - 
- - - - - - 3 - -
2 - 6 - - 7 - - - 
4 - - - 4 - - 3 -
```

I thought of doing it this way:

```
public void display_grid()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < Sodoku_Gri.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < Sodoku_Gri.GetLength(1); col++)
            {

                Console.Write(Sodoku_Gri[row, col]);
                Console.Write("  ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I just can't understand why the 2d array printed 9 times with additional ------------ in the last row!

It should be a 2d array with spacing between each element like I showed the data in the file but that is without spacing.

Comment: I don't understand the question: The only difference between what *is* written and what *should be* written seem to be the linebreaks, that are apparently created by your call `Console.WriteLine();`. Where are there any "additional --------"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper He wasn't escaping markdown, take a look now.

Comment: The only difference I see are the extra spaces. Is that it?

Comment: output is that 2d array is printed 9 times!

Answer (score 1):

you are splitting the data into lines, and it appears your intention in the inner loop is to process the characters in the current line. However, you are actually processing the entire file for each line iteration, which is why your output contains all the file's characters * the number of lines. Try this adjustment instead:

```
   public void populate_grid_by_file()
        {
            String store_data_from_file = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
                {
                    store_data_from_file = reader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            string[] line = store_data_from_file.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                //string[] alphabet = store_data_from_file.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string[] alphabet = line[i].Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.Length; j++)
                {
                    Sodoku_Gri[i, j] = alphabet[j];
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: what would be the change sir??

Comment: wait i just figured ur change

Comment: not working grid isn;t printed properly! first it was the problem of duplicated printing only! now even the file is not being loaded properly!

Comment: please read the question again sir! some editing has been made!

Comment: @haris Ok I've update the answer to include the ENTIRE function, as it apparently wasn't understood to just change the appropriate line. Just copy/paste the entire function into VS and try again.

Comment: sir my file has 9 lines with 9 alphabets in each line without space bt after 9 alphabets newline is there!