# Duplication of row while reading from file

Tags: c#, file, file-io, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [printing 2d array in c# through for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769448/printing-2d-array-in-c-sharp-through-for-loop)

this is how my data in txt file:

```
1--2--3--    
3-4-4-5--    
-7-3-4---
7--5--3-6    
--7---4--    
3-2--4-5-    
------3--    
2-6--7---    
4---4--3-
```

without any empty line between! have this formatting issue above!

is my c# code to do file reading with the display too:

```
public void populate_grid_by_file()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
               new System.IO.StreamReader("data.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < Sodoku_Gri.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Sodoku_Gri.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Sodoku_Gri[i,j] = line[j];
                        Console.Write(line[j].ToString());

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            file.Close();
            // Suspend the screen.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

but when i display my array with the  file reading above it is like:

```
1--2--3--1--2--3--    
3-4-4-5--3-4-4-5--    
-7-3-4----7-3-4---    
7--5--3-67--5--3-6    
--7---4----7---4--    
3-2--4-5-3-2--4-5-    
------3--------3--    
2-6--7---2-6--7---    
4---4--3-4---4--3-
```

cnt understand why duplication! help!

When i debugged i found that there was a problem in the line:

```
Console.Write(line[j].ToString());
```

it means that automatically elements are not being loaded into the array here:

```
Sodoku_Gri[i,j] = line[j];
```

Kindly help me with this!

Comment: You should **not** just re-post the same question if you don't like the answers or don't get any.  For starters, you should answer the questions asked of you in the comments of your previous questions.

Comment: @L.B And yet you keep posting them...

Comment: could you people please ignore the rest and focus on the question? that is the problem! i still dnt have my ans yet =) please sir kindly see my comments below to the answer!

Comment: [**How does accepting an answer w0rk?**](http://goo.gl/wGDfS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You display the line once, character by character here:

```
    Console.Write(line[j].ToString());
```

And then the full line all at once here:

```
     Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: the main issue is not the printing sir! even the file reading is not done properly!

Comment: Sodoku_Gri[i,j] = line[j]; now when after correcting what you just mentioned when i called my display grid function that is just a collection of for loops to display my grid my output is all "-" except 3-4 places in 2-d grid